# Facing trouble while fetching data to yajra datatables with model laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable, model

I  have the following three table in laravel app

purchases table

`id, name, price`

Products table

`id, purchase_id, price`

sales table

`id, product_id, quantity, total-price`

The sales table belongs to products table refers product id while products table belong to purchases table refers purchase id

Now i I want to fetch data in sales tables but also in need the name of the product which come from purchases table the final results must be

new table

`id, product_id, quantity, total-price, name`

my query below fetch only sales table data

`$sales = Sales::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), array($from_date, $to_date))->get();`

here I return yajira datatable

`return Datatables::of($sales)->addIndexColumn()->make(true);`

other code in models

sales model

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}

public function purchase()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Purchase::class,'purchase_id');
}
```

products model

```
public function purchase()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Purchase::class);
}
```

purchases model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do join operation for this.

```
Sales::query()
      ->leftJoin('products', 'sales.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
      ->leftJoin('purchases', 'products.purchase_id', '=', 'purchases.id')
      ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(sales.created_at)'), [$from_date, $to_date])
      ->select('sales.id', 'sales.product_id', 'sales.quantity', 'sales.total-price', 'purchases.name');
```

You can learn more from [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins)

Comment: This is a pointless complication when the relationship is already defined in Eloquent.